# Ruby libraries for command-prompt-based applications

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-prompt

I'm looking to create a Ruby application with a command-prompt-based interface. By "command-prompt-interface," I mean something similar to irb, but note that I do not mean actually executing Ruby code. The gems I'm finding via Google seem to be more suited to CLIs like git, not an actual prompt like irb.

I need to be able to define commands and handlers for those commands, so something like:

```
(prompt) helloworld
Hello World
(prompt)
```

Validation and a built-in help system would also be good extras, as would the ability to execute a single command from the command line (calling it from the shell `cliapp.rb -c helloworld`).

I'm able to create this from scratch, but if there are any libraries available I'd prefer to use that rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Methadone](http://www.naildrivin5.com/blog/2011/12/19/methadone-the-awesome-cli-library.html), which was created by David Bryant Copeland, the author of the book "[Build Awesome Command-Line Apps in Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/dccar/build-awesome-command-line-applications-in-ruby)". You may want to check out the book as well.

See [this blog post](http://www.naildrivin5.com/blog/2011/12/19/methadone-the-awesome-cli-library.html) for more information.